# How to check for the presence of a tilde (~) at the end of a text string?

Tags: xstring, tilde

How do I get to 'true'?

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
  
\IfEndWith{string~}{\textasciitilde}{true}{false}
\IfEndWith{string~}{\textasciitilde{}}{true}{false}
\IfEndWith{string~}{$\sim$}{true}{false}
\IfEndWith{string~}{\~{}}{true}{false}

\end{document}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
  
\IfEndWith{string~}{\textasciitilde}{true}{false}
\IfEndWith{string~}{\textasciitilde{}}{true}{false}
\IfEndWith{string~}{$\sim$}{true}{false}
\IfEndWith{string~}{\~{}}{true}{false}
\IfEndWith{string~}{~}{true}{false}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ... I missed what was right in front of me! Thanks for the quick wake-up! I wonder how often I over-complicate my attitude toward LaTeX?

Comment: @RosesBouquet often LaTeX indeed _is_ very complicated - but `xstring` is a very well designed package that "just works" in many situations where you would expect that more complicated code is needed.

Comment: I'm so embarrassed that I did not see the obvious ... been up for too many hours ... thank you so much for the quick fix ... and the kind thought! I too often complicate the obvious ...

Comment: Sometimes a cigar ... is just a cigar! Sometimes a tilde ... is just a tilde!